# Chaining code marks with single quotation marks on the comments

Tags: support, bug

I tried to comment [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57700765/3241041) with code marks, but seems like that we can't put too many code blocks on comments, or there is a bug when chaining code marks " ` " with single quotation marks " ' " on the comments.

For example, this works here:

You can specify the pod path on the Podfile with `pod 'FolioReaderKit', :path => '../Path_To_Local_Pod_Folder'` if you use it local, or `pod 'FolioReaderKit', :git => 'github.com/FolioReaderKitCopy'` if you copy the repository on GitHub.

**Edit**

Turns out that spaces between code marks works on questions, but not on comments.

Comment: Same here: You can specify the pod path on the Podfile with ` pod 'FolioReaderKit', :path => '../Path_To_Local_Pod_Folder' ` if you use it local, or ` pod 'FolioReaderKit', :git => 'github.com/FolioReaderKitCopy' ` if you copy the repository on GitHub.

Comment: but `this` works

Comment: You have a space between the backtick and the text. Just remove it

Comment: Test: You can specify the pod path on the Podfile with `pod 'FolioReaderKit', :path => '../Path_To_Local_Pod_Folder' ` if you use it local, or `pod 'FolioReaderKit', :git => 'github.com/FolioReaderKitCopy' ` if you copy the repository on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But why does space between code marks works on questions?

Comment: Different markdown parsers? No idea. Comments are horrible for formatting, and markdown itself is limited (different parsers can parse edge-cases like this one differently). Just generally, avoid spaces between text and formatting tokens. If you need space to be a part of the initial formatting, you'll have to use manual <code></code> elements (if you're doing it inline), which doesn't work with comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that spaces between code marks works on questions and answers, but not on comments.

Comment: Spaces work between code-backticks in comments, but only if the space is *not adjacent* to the backtick delimiter. `foo bar`. Leading/trailing spaces aren't permitted, for some reason

Comment: seems like a... `( ••)` _waste of space..._ `( ••)>⌐■-■` `(⌐■_■)`